# Passing local variables in one function to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

I am stuck at this problem. I have this code (string is of the form: 'var1,var2,var3', and someIdArray is an array containing some id's):

```
function myFunction1(variable,string)
  {
  var myArray = string.split(',');
  for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
    {
    for (j=0;j<someIdArray[j].length;j++)
      {
      document.getElementById(someIdArray[j]).onclick=function() { myFunction2(variable,myArray[i]) };
      }
    }
  }
function myFunction2(variable1,variable2)
  {
  alert(variable1);
  alert(variable2);
  }
```

Now when I click an element with an id in someIdArray, myFunction2 runs, and I get variable1 as I put it in myFunction1, but variable2 is undefined. How can I make sure that the onclick I defined for the element I clicked has fixed variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function myFunction1(variable,string)
{
  var myArray = string.split(',');
  for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
  {
    for (var j=0;j<someIdArray.length;j++)
    {
      document.getElementById(someIdArray[j]).onclick=function()
      {
         var localI = i;
         myFunction2(variable,myArray[localI]);
      }
    }
  }
}
function myFunction2(variable1,variable2)
{
  alert(variable1);
  alert(variable2);
}
```

The problem in your code is that `i` and `j` are global vars because you didn't add the `var` keyword to them.

So you pass a global var that gets increased to `myArray.length` to the function.

If you do `myArray[myArray.length]` you will get `undefined`.

What I did in the above code was store a local variable that gets encapsulated in the `onClick` function scope.

Another way would be this:

```
for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
{
    for (var j=0;j<someIdArray.length;j++)
    {
      var myArrayIElement = myArray[i];
      document.getElementById(someIdArray[j]).onclick=function()
      {

         myFunction2(variable,myArrayIElement);
      }
    }
}
```

Here you make a variable with the value from `myArray[i]` and pass it to the `onClick` function, instead of passing the `i` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your inner for loop:

```
for (j=0;j<someIdArray[j].length;j++)
```

you probably want `someIdArray.length` rather than the length of the `j`th element

Comment: True...but it still won't solve the problem.

Comment: ...aaaand that was a typo. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your corrected code here, This is a problem with scope,
    you have did two wrong things,
     1. the someIdArray length you've got is wrong
     2. Haven't assign array element and pass to the click event

```
function myFunction1(variable, string) {
    var myArray = string.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        var arrEle = myArray[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < someIdArray.length; j++) {
            document.getElementById(someIdArray[j]).onclick = function() {
                myFunction2(variable, arrEle);
            };
        }
    }
}

function myFunction2(variable1, variable2) {
    alert(variable1);
    alert(variable2);
}
```